# Variable Scope in nodejs misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, promise

I'm having trouble understanding why returning a array from another function is only limited to one block of code. IE:

```
exports.join = function(req, res){
  User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {
     var dupe = []; //placeholder array
     var arr = user.forms_container.joinList;
     var title = user.forms_container.title;
     arr.forEach(function (rep) {
      //console.log(rep);
      Report.findById(rep).deepPopulate('subreport.subreport.subreport.subreport.subreport.subreport').execAsync()
      .then(function(doc) {
        //console.log(doc);
        dupe.push(doc);
        treeCycle(doc, dupe);
        console.log(dupe);
      }).catch(function(err) {
        throw err;
      });
      tracker = tracker + 1;

      if(tracker == arr.length) {
        console.log(dupe); //returns [];
        var counter = 0;
        var masterbody;
        for(var x = 0; x < dupe.length; x++) {
           masterbody = masterbody + dupe[x].body;
           counter = counter + 1;
        }
        if(counter==dupe.length) {
          newDoc.body = masterbody;
          //newDoc.save();
          res.json(newDoc);
        }
      }
     });

  });
};
```

Once, I call treeCycle, it will iterate through that function(recursive function) and begin to fill up the array "dupe", if I log it in the console right after, it shows it being completed, here is the console c/p'd:

```
[ { _id: 55c35cd942dd12ec19b30f2e,
    owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
    title: 'Chrome1',
    date: 'Thu Aug 06 2015 09:10:49 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
    body: '123213',
    __v: 0,
    isCompleted: false,
    subreport: [],
    authors: [ 'Karan Kotwal' ],
    author: [ 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8 ] } ]
[ { _id: 55c35cd942dd12ec19b30f2e,
    owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
    title: 'Chrome1',
    date: 'Thu Aug 06 2015 09:10:49 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
    body: '123213',
    __v: 0,
    isCompleted: false,
    subreport: [],
    authors: [ 'Karan Kotwal' ],
    author: [ 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8 ] },
  { _id: 55c8d774e904bc141681e115,
    body: 'dddd',
    owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
    date: 'Mon Aug 10 2015 12:55:16 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
    title: 'herdrute',
    __v: 1,
    isCompleted: false,
    subreport: [],
    authors: [ 'Karan Kotwal' ],
    author: [ 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8 ] } ]
[ { _id: 55c35cd942dd12ec19b30f2e,
    owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
    title: 'Chrome1',
    date: 'Thu Aug 06 2015 09:10:49 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
    body: '123213',
    __v: 0,
    isCompleted: false,
    subreport: [],
    authors: [ 'Karan Kotwal' ],
    author: [ 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8 ] },
  { _id: 55c8d774e904bc141681e115,
    body: 'dddd',
    owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
    date: 'Mon Aug 10 2015 12:55:16 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
    title: 'herdrute',
    __v: 1,
    isCompleted: false,
    subreport: [],
    authors: [ 'Karan Kotwal' ],
    author: [ 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8 ] },
  { _id: 55bf7465c60c959015dee0ed,
    owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
    title: 'ffefeeffefeeffefefe',
    date: 'Mon Aug 03 2015 10:02:13 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
    body: 'efefefefef',
    __v: 0,
    isCompleted: false,
    subreport: [],
    authors: [ 'Karan Kotwal' ],
    author: [ 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8 ] } ]
[ { _id: 55c35cd942dd12ec19b30f2e,
    owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
    title: 'Chrome1',
    date: 'Thu Aug 06 2015 09:10:49 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
    body: '123213',
    __v: 0,
    isCompleted: false,
    subreport: [],
    authors: [ 'Karan Kotwal' ],
    author: [ 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8 ] },
  { _id: 55c8d774e904bc141681e115,
    body: 'dddd',
    owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
    date: 'Mon Aug 10 2015 12:55:16 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
    title: 'herdrute',
    __v: 1,
    isCompleted: false,
    subreport: [],
    authors: [ 'Karan Kotwal' ],
    author: [ 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8 ] },
  { _id: 55bf7465c60c959015dee0ed,
    owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
    title: 'ffefeeffefeeffefefe',
    date: 'Mon Aug 03 2015 10:02:13 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
    body: 'efefefefef',
    __v: 0,
    isCompleted: false,
    subreport: [],
    authors: [ 'Karan Kotwal' ],
    author: [ 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8 ] },
  { _id: 55c361705d00464419a1d40c,
    owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
    title: 'IE11',
    date: 'Thu Aug 06 2015 09:30:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
    body: 'PEWPEWPEWPW',
    __v: 1,
    isCompleted: false,
    subreport:
     [ { _id: 55ca4d5456f8cdb416d36092,
         body: 'testest',
         owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
         date: 'Tue Aug 11 2015 15:30:28 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
         title: 'Sub1',
         __v: 2,
         parentReport: 55c361705d00464419a1d40c,
         isCompleted: false,
         subreport: [Object],
         authors: [Object],
         author: [Object] } ],
    authors: [ 'Karan Kotwal' ],
    author: [ 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8 ] },
  { _id: 55ca4d5456f8cdb416d36092,
    body: 'testest',
    owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
    date: 'Tue Aug 11 2015 15:30:28 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
    title: 'Sub1',
    __v: 2,
    parentReport: 55c361705d00464419a1d40c,
    isCompleted: false,
    subreport:
     [ { _id: 55ca53728ecc9400150610b6,
         body: 'sadsadasdasdasdadasdsadasdasEnter subreport here',
         owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
         date: 'Tue Aug 11 2015 15:56:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
         title: 'Sub1\'s sub1',
         __v: 1,
         parentReport: 55ca4d5456f8cdb416d36092,
         isCompleted: false,
         subreport: [],
         authors: [Object],
         author: [Object] } ],
    authors: [ 'Jeff The man' ],
    author: [ 55ad14bac2419660021d80b0 ] },
  { _id: 55ca53728ecc9400150610b6,
    body: 'sadsadasdasdasdadasdsadasdasEnter subreport here',
    owner: 55a80b8404dc0dc8187395d8,
    date: 'Tue Aug 11 2015 15:56:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
    title: 'Sub1\'s sub1',
    __v: 1,
    parentReport: 55ca4d5456f8cdb416d36092,
    isCompleted: false,
    subreport: [],
    authors: [ 'Empty Empty' ],
    author: [ 55bbbc20877f48a01bf0c8d9 ] } ]
```

However doing so, calling the console for the final version of the array dupe returns empty. I do it in the block `if(tracker == array.length);` I thought that its scope would be throughout this whole function since I initialized it in the begginning.

TreeCycle:

```
function treeCycle(doc, arr) {
  if(doc.subreport.length != 0) {
    for (var x = 0; x < doc.subreport.length; x++){
      arr.push(doc.subreport[x]);
      //console.log(arr);
      if(doc.subreport[x].subreport.length != 0) {
        treeCycle(doc.subreport[x], arr);
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    return arr;
  }
};
```

Comment: You're pushing to the array inside an async function, and trying to log those changes outside the async callback for `then()`

Comment: I don't see any ES6 in the question?

Comment: You cannot use promises in a loop like that. Look into `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an async problem, your `if(tracker == arr.length) {` part is running before the tree cycle. When your async task is done you need to then call your `if(tracker == arr.length) {` part.

Example:

```
exports.join = function(req, res) {
    User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {
        var dupe = []; //placeholder array
        var arr = user.forms_container.joinList;
        var title = user.forms_container.title;
        arr.forEach(function(rep) {
            //console.log(rep);
            Report.findById(rep).deepPopulate('subreport.subreport.subreport.subreport.subreport.subreport').execAsync()
                .then(function(doc) {
                    //console.log(doc);
                    dupe.push(doc);
                    treeCycle(doc, dupe);
                    console.log(dupe);

                    tracker = tracker + 1;

                    if (tracker == arr.length) {
                        console.log(dupe); //returns [];
                        var counter = 0;
                        var masterbody;
                        for (var x = 0; x < dupe.length; x++) {
                            masterbody = masterbody + dupe[x].body;
                            counter = counter + 1;
                        }
                        if (counter == dupe.length) {
                            newDoc.body = masterbody;
                            //newDoc.save();
                            res.json(newDoc);
                        }
                    }

                }).catch(function(err) {
                    throw err;
                });
        });

    });
};
```

Comment: If I wanted to do it in order, where the treeCycle would complete its cycle, then move on to the next element and treeCycle on that would you recommend promises for that as well?

Comment: Personally I just use the callback pattern. But either would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely a problem with how you are using the [promises](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/). I'd recommend reading up on them to see how they work and how you should refactor your code to use them better.

If you move that `if (tracker...` block into the `.then(` callback (or another `.then`) it might work.